# I want to create api using laravel for fetch image which are stored in database in blob format but getting this errors

Tags: php, laravel, api, laravel-8

I want to create api using laravel for fetch image which are stored in database in blob format but getting this errors

```
public function show()
 {
   $product= Product::all();
   return response($product);
 }
```

details

[image]

[image]

errors

[image]

Comment: Could you show us $product details ? please

Comment: fyi, the `show()` method is usually used to show details for __one__ item

Answer (score 3):

Because your `product->image` contains bytes content, encoder from `response` can't properly deserialise it.

You can't pass pure byte code in a json response, use some kind of casting, read in docs ["Eloquent: Mutators & Casting"](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-mutators)

Ideally you should [create a custom casting](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#custom-casts) which will transform your blob data into a transportable form: `base64`, `hex`, whatever you like best.

Here's an example for you

```
<?php
 
namespace App\Casts;
 
use Illuminate\Contracts\Database\Eloquent\CastsAttributes;
 
class Blob implements CastsAttributes
{
    public function get($model, $key, $value, $attributes)
    {
        return base64_decode($value);
    }
 
    public function set($model, $key, $value, $attributes)
    {
        return base64_encode($value);
    }
}


......

use App\Casts\Blob;


class Product extends Model
{
    protected $casts = [
        'image' => Blob::class,
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

the format of `image` column is binary. you need to encode it as base64 to use it.
just you need is a getter. you can accomplish this using cast or simle accesser.

#### accesser

```
class Product extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public function getImageAttribute($value)
    {
        return 'data:image/png;base64,' . base64_encode($value);
    }

}
```

now you have the base64 format of image and can use it in `src` attribute of image element . or even you can store the base64 string in file system.